# Get inventory scripts from source control in awx

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower, ansible-awx

In AWX, currently if you select inventory scripts > Custom scripts, you can only paste the code in the input box. Is there a way to pull the script from source control ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the link to the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/administration/scm-inv-source.html) describing the process of checking in custom inventory scripts in source control. But, I didn't got it right in the first attempt.

So, here we go...

- Add your custom inventory script to version control inside inventory folder. (eg: inventory/get_my_inventory.py in git_project)
- Make sure you are giving executable permissions for this script before checking in to the repo otherwise AWX won't recognize the script and display in the list.

Now in AWX...

- Click **inventory** > **sources** > **new sources**(+)
- Select **Create Source** > **Source** > **Sourced from a project**.
- Now in **project** select the project which has the custom inventory script file. (eg: git_project)
- Now your custom script should show up in the **inventory file** drop down. (eg: inventory/get_my_inventory.py )

Well, its a simple process but I had to spend few hours to get it right. Hope that's of some help!